# Python Pandas DataFrame: How to process a column consisting of dicts into multiple columns determined by the keys of the dicts?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, dataframe

Inside one of my pandas DataFrame, there's a column containing a dictionary or dict in each of the rows.

For example one of the rows would contain "{'a':1,'b':2}"

I need to make a DataFrame with 'a' and 'b' as columns or however many unique keys there are in all of the dicts contained in the column.

For example, if one row contains "{'a':1,'b':2}" while another has "{'a':1,'c':2}" I need to make a DataFrame with 'a', 'b', and 'c' as its columns. The column names would be the keys of the dicts and the rows will contain the values of the dicts. The index of the DataFrame would be the same as the original.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use `DataFrame` constructor with converting `data` column to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) and then to `list`:

```
#borrowing sample from DeepSpace's answer
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'c': 4}]})
print (df)
               data
0  {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
1  {'a': 3, 'c': 4}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['data'].values.tolist(), index=df.index)
print (df1)
   a    b    c
0  1  2.0  NaN
1  3  NaN  4.0
```

Comment: Thanks for making my answer look ridiculous ;).

Comment: Any idea why pandas (or numpy?) decided to leave `1` and `3` as int but `2`  and `4` became a float?

Comment: because `NaN`s values in columns cast to float.